# Iterating over multiple CSVs and joining with Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I have several csv files with the same headers and the same IDs. I am attempting to iterate to merge all files up to one indexed '31'. In my while loop, I'm trying to initialise the merged dataset so it can be used for the remainder of the loop. In the last line, I was told that the 'local variable merged may not have been initialised'. How should I instead be doing this?

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("testSql")
            .master("local[*]")
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:tmp")
            .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> first = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("mypath/01.csv");
Dataset<Row> second = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("mypath/02.csv");
    
IntStream.range(3, 31)
    .forEach(i -> {
        while(i==3) {
            Dataset<Row> merged = first.join(second, first.col("customer_id").equalTo(second.col("customer_id")));
            }
        Dataset<Row> next = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("mypath/"+i+".csv");
        Dataset<Row> merged  = merged.join(next, merged.col("customer_id").equalTo(next.col("customer_id")));
```

Comment: 1. `Dataset<Row> merged  = merged...`, from compiler standpoint, may happen to use `merged` before its initialized.   2. your `while` looks like a classical endless loop.

Comment: How should I be going about this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** based on feedback in the comments.

Following your pattern, something like this would work:

```
Dataset<Row> ds1 = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("mypath/01.csv");
Dataset<?>[] result = {ds1};
IntStream.range(2, 31)
    .forEach(i -> {
        Dataset<Row> next = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("mypath/"+i+".csv");
        result[0] = result[0].join(next, "customer_id");
    });
```

We're wrapping `Dataset` into an array in order to work around the restriction on variable capture in lambda expressions.

The more straightforward way, for this particular case, is to simply use a for-loop rather than `stream.forEach`:

```
Dataset<Row> result = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("mypath/01.csv");
for( int i = 2 ; i < 31 ; i++ ) {
  Dataset<Row> next = spark.read().option("header", true).csv("mypath/"+i+".csv");
  result[0] = result[0].join(next, "customer_id");
};
```

Comment: This looks good but on the last line, I am getting the error: 'Local variable result defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final'

Comment: Have opted to use a regular for loop rather than a lambda expression and it works fine ^_^

Comment: @user3058703 Ah! variable capture in lambdas! Totally forgot about it, thanks for the feedback!